# Which kind of tubing is best for permanent above-ground in a cold climate?

Tags: plumbing, irrigation

I want to set up an irrigation system that runs from a hose outlet on the side of our house. Part of it is going to be permanent and above-ground. We live in Minnesota, so it gets cold in winter and hot in summer. Naturally we're not going to use irrigation in winter, and can let the pipes drain. What kinds of pipe/tubing are both UV-resistant and cold/hot resistant?

From what I've seen:

- C/PVC is UV-resistant but too brittle in cold
- PEX is cold-resistant but not UV-resistant
- Polyethylene is resistant to UV and cold? But I'm confused because PEX is made with polyethylene.

Comment: Made with and made from can be two different things.  Cold resistant and Minnesota cold can also be two different things.  I am in Eastern Ontario, you can keep your cold.  UV protection can be a simple covering.

Answer (score 2):

Standard black polyethylene "well pipe" (or the thinner grades for irrigation-only use) are rated for sunlight exposure. The black coloration is part of that (prevents UV light from getting into the plastic to degrade it.)

Comment: How does that handle the cold of a MN winter?

Comment: Fine, if you don't leave it full of water or take a sledgehammer to it at -40°